Local Development: Cloudflare Worker (HonoJS) Accessing R2 Files
I'm developing a Cloudflare Worker using HonoJS and leveraging Cloudflare R2 for object storage. In production, I've successfully enabled R2 Subdomain public access, allowing me to access files using the provided URL.
However, during local development (npm run dev), the uploaded files are stored within the codebase in .wrangler/state/../r2/Blob instead of the actual R2 bucket. This raises the question:
What mechanism can I use to access these files while running the Worker locally?
Is there a way to construct a local URL that mimics the production subdomain behavior, or is there a recommended approach for simulating R2 interaction during development?
Additional Information:

Tech stack: Cloudflare Worker (HonoJS), Cloudflare R2
I've explored using environment variables, but I'm unsure how to effectively configure them for this scenario.

Desired Outcome:
I'd like to find a solution that allows me to test my Worker's functionality with R2 file access during local development without compromising the security of the actual R2 objects.

we can serve files from the bucket ourselves (aka proxy) instead of accessing them through a dedicated public URL (configured in r2 dashboard e.g assets.example.com). It should be the same in terms of performance (I think?) since we're still applying cache-control and serving from Cloudflare CDN. Or we can try to replace in production with a public URL, but losing the ability for auth check.
import * as v from 'valibot';
import { vValidator } from '@hono/valibot-validator';
import { HTTPException } from 'hono/http-exception';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { factory } from 'server/factory';

export const r2 = factory
    .createApp()

    .get('/:key', async c => {
        if (!c.var.user) throw new HTTPException(401, { message: 'Unauthorized' });

        const key = c.req.param('key');
        const object = await c.env.BUCKET.get(key);

        if (!object) return c.text('Object Not Found', { status: 404 });

        const headers = new Headers();
        // ? Devalue error: Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs
        // object.writeHttpMetadata(headers);
        object.httpMetadata && headers.append('content-type', object.httpMetadata.contentType!);
        headers.append('cache-control', 'immutable, no-transform, max-age=31536000');
        headers.append('etag', object.httpEtag);
        headers.append('date', object.uploaded.toUTCString());

        return new Response(object?.body, { headers });
    })

    .delete('/:key', async c => {
        if (!c.var.user) throw new HTTPException(401, { message: 'Unauthorized' });
        const key = c.req.param('key');
        await c.env.BUCKET.delete(key);
        return c.text(`${key} file was deleted`);
    })

    .delete('/', vValidator('form', v.object({ keys: v.array(v.string()) })), async c => {
        if (!c.var.user) throw new HTTPException(401, { message: 'Unauthorized' });
        const { keys } = c.req.valid('form');
        await Promise.all(keys.map(async key => await c.env.BUCKET.delete(key)));
        return c.json({ status: 'ok', message: `(${keys.join(', ')}) keys have been deleted` } as const);
    })

    .put(
        '/',
        vValidator('form', v.object({ files: v.array(v.pipe(v.instance(File), v.mimeType(['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp']), v.maxSize(1e8))) })),
        async c => {
            if (!c.var.user) throw new HTTPException(401, { message: 'Unauthorized' });

            const { files } = c.req.valid('form');

            const result = await Promise.all(
                files.map(async file => {
                    const id = nanoid(10);
                    const fileBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
                    const key = `${id}` as const;

                    await c.env.BUCKET.put(key, fileBuffer, {
                        httpMetadata: { contentType: file.type },
                        customMetadata: {
                            fileName: file.name,
                            fileSize: String(file.size),
                        },
                    });

                    return { name: file.name, key, src: `/api/v1/r2/${key}` as const };
                }),
            );

            return c.json({ status: 'ok', files: result });
        },
    );

///

const app = factory.createApp();

app.route('/api/v1/r2', r2);

export default app;

